# How to solve "The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:bloc_sample/blocs/product_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../blocs/cart_bloc.dart';
import '../models/cart.dart';

class ProductListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("eCommerce"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/cart"),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: buildProductList(),
    );
  }

  buildProductList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      initialData: productBloc.getAll(),
      stream: productBloc.getStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data.length > 0 //ERROR
            ? buildProductListItems(snapshot)
            : Center(
                child: Text("No data"),
              );
      },
    );
  }

  buildProductListItems(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          final list = snapshot.data;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(list[index].name),
            subtitle: Text(list[index].price.toString()),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {
                cartBloc.addToCart(Cart(list[index], 1));
              },
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. (Documentation)  Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

I tried "?" or "!" but it doesn't work. Can You help me? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Would you please show in which line or function is it showing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler isn't sure that `snapshot.data` isn't null. It also doesn't know that its a `List`. (I assume its a `List` since you're accessing the `length` property).

So here you need a combo of the bang operator `!` and a type cast.

If it's a `Map` just change the typecast to `Map`.

```
(snapshot.data! as List).length > 0
```

The other option is a null check.

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
    return buildProductListItems(snapshot);
 } else {
    return Center(child: Text("No data"),
 );
}
```

Which one to choose depends on your implementation of `product.getStream`. If it's always at least an empty list and never null, then use the first option. If it's actually `null` if there's no data, then use the null check.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I will do it this way from now on.